# RAM failure with threadripper build

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, threadripper

A new workstation has been built on a remote-site but we’re having trouble getting the memory working.

**Build information:**

- Antec P7 Silent Mid Tower Case - Black
- ASUS PRIME X399-A AMD Socket TR4 Motherboard (latest BIOS installed)
- AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2950X 3.5GHz Sixteen Core
- NH-U14S TR4-SP3 Ryzen Threadripper Epyc CPU Cooler
- Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (1x 16GB) 2666MHz DDR4 (serial CMK32GX4M2B3000C15)
- PNY Quadro P620 DVI 2GB Pro Graphics Card
- EVGA 850 GQ 850W Modular
- Intel SSD 760p Series 128GB M.2-2280 NVMe PCIe
- Samsung 970 EVO 1TB M.2-2280 NVMe PCIe SSD

Simulation application crashes under load when all RAM was installed. When memtest was ran, it failed.

The test passed only when installing four slots. With 6 or 8 slots populated, memes failed (we didn’t try 1-3 – see picture below).

When replacing with the other 4 memory modules, they also passed memtest, so we concluded that the memory modules are all OK.

Anybody else had any forms of compatibility issues with these products? Or know of any specific settings needed in the BIOS that we are missing?

As for the RAM, frequencies ranging from 2133 MHz  to 3000 are visible - which makes me think something isn't set correctly.

Please find extensive screenshots of the workstations BIOS configuration here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhyjj.jpg

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same memory kit on a 1950x, in a quad-channel configuration. It's supposed to be an Intel RAM kit, so the XMP profiles have timings that don't play well.

You'll want to go into the memory timing settings and enter the CAS latency settings manually.

Through trial and error and gossip, I found that CL 14-16-27-48 gets me a 1T command rate and stable system. Oh, and I run the kit at 2996 instead of 3000.